# Splitting a bounding box map into multiple zones with a certain factor and return it in GeoJson

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, geojson

I have a function that has the following inputs:
These are bounding coordinates:

1. Northlimit
2. Southlimit
3. Eastlimit
4. Westlimit
5. Factor

This function takes in these coordinates and should split them into multiple zones based on that factor. So for example, if the factor is 10, then I would have 10x10 which is 100 zones. I'm wondering how it could be split into those zones and also output it in geojson format.

For example:

[[[5.9559111595,45.8179931641],[10.4920501709,45.8179931641],[10.4920501709,47.808380127],[5.9559111595,47.808380127],[5.9559111595,45.8179931641]]]

Comment: What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: zone_table = list()
    zone_factor *=zone_factor
    longs = np.linspace(westlimit, eastlimit, zone_factor+1 )
    lats = np.linspace(southlimit, northlimit, zone_factor+1)
    zone_table = [[[[lats[i-1],longs[i-1]], [lats[i-1],longs[i]],[lats[i],longs[i]],[lats[i],longs[i-1]],  [lats[i-1],longs[i-1]]]] for i in range(1,zone_factor+1)]

Comment: This returns it in a diagonal format, not a box. Like a diagonal of boxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
def createZoneTable(zone_factor,westlimit, southlimit, eastlimit, northlimit):
    zone_table = list()
    longs = np.linspace(westlimit, eastlimit, zone_factor +1 )
    lats = np.linspace(southlimit, northlimit, zone_factor +1 )
    
    for i in range(1,len(longs)):
        for j in range(1,len(lats)):
            zone_table.append([[[lats[j-1],longs[i-1]], [lats[j-1],longs[i]],[lats[j],longs[i]],[lats[j],longs[i-1]],  [lats[j-1],longs[i-1]]]])
    return zone_table
createZoneTable(10,westlimit=0, southlimit=0, eastlimit=10, northlimit=10)
```